# Style close reason to look like an answer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I tend to see the big grey close box as something of a "DENIED" graphic; the text seems secondary, and is easy to skip over. And from the behaviour of users, this seems to be a common view. Which is a pity, because the descriptions have quite a bit of practical advice.

It got me wondering whether the text would get more eyes if it looked (at first glance) like a community-posted / community wiki answer, with more focus on the text (no title). Maybe with a few upvotes (since, after all, up to 5 people voted for it).

I'm curious to see what people think. I don't think I've given enough thought to make a feature request; this was just a thought which occurred after seeing a close box.

Comment: You're proposing that the automatic banner's stlying be changed to resemble an answer's, not that an individual close voter should post an "answer" about closure, right? Your title strongly implies the latter.

Comment: What problem would this solve? People will see there aren't any answers and that no new ones get added and on top of that the message is duplicated as a replacement for the answer field.

Comment: @JoshCaswell good point. I've changed the title to something clearer.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's not about making anything available which isn't already there; it's about making it feel nicer. Consider a new user who posts a silly question. They get a big banner saying **Closed**, and just give up. Other people have shown that hardly any closed questions get fixed up; maybe making the closed screen friendlier (and putting it where a user wants to read it) will help.

Comment: If people are ignoring it, as you say, perhaps the problem is that the close box isn't *more* like "a DENIED graphic".

Answer (score 10):

The fact that the close box is somewhat intimidating seems as though it would be a *good thing*.  It would discourage users to ask questions that do not follow the guidelines.  In addition, it shows very clearly to other users that the question is not acceptable for Stack Overflow (or is a duplicate, thus, still not very acceptable).  This prevents them from having an inclination to answer the question or ask a similar one if they are a new user and do not yet know what constitutes a good question.

Still, if this were to be attempted to be resolved, an answer would most likely not be the best representation of a close reason.  New users may believe that they should write an answer about why questions are bad if they see one, creating a ton of low quality questions.

It is possible that in order for it to look friendlier, it could be a lighter grey, but other than this, it just seems as though it makes sense for it to look as it does.

Comment: "New users may believe that they should write an answer about why questions are bad if they see one": true, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: To be honest, I think the title is the bigger issue (not the background colour); reading "Closed by..." or "Put on hold as..." immediately makes the rest of the text feel unimportant. Perhaps it would benefit from simply swapping things around to put the friendly description first.

Comment: It's true that it may be shocking to see "Closed by...," but "Put on hold as..." is meant to signify "This question is not appropriate as it currently stands, but it can be improved.  It is simply put on hold until further notice."  Or, maybe that's just my own interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of potential answerers, I think it's a good thing that there's a big grey box blocking the answer area.

It would be pretty confusing if there was a special kind of answer that looked the same but prevented other answers from being posted. "Why can't I post?! That doesn't even answer the question, but I have a solution!"

(Not to mention, [as Anonymous already has](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256081/603977), the potential for copycat behavior of users who can't cast close votes, which would require clean-up and generate aggravation all around.)